# ListView with footer row, right align column

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, listview, footer

I've got this template for a ListView with a footer row. It uses gridview columns from the original ListView.

```
<Style x:Key="FrozenRowScrollViewer" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <DockPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                                      local:ScrollViewerBinding.HorizontalOffset="{Binding Value, ElementName=PART_HorizontalScrollBar}"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      Focusable="false"
                                      Visibility="{Binding TemplatedParent.HasFooter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                            <GridViewRowPresenter  
                                Margin="2,0,2,0"
                                Content="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource summaryConverter}}"
                                Columns="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                        <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      Focusable="false">
                            <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter
                                    Margin="2,0,2,0"
                                    Columns="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                    ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                    ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                    ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                    AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.AllowsColumnReorder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                    ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                    ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </ScrollViewer>

                        <ScrollContentPresenter Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Local"
                                                CanContentScroll="True"
                                                CanHorizontallyScroll="False"
                                                CanVerticallyScroll="False" />
                    </DockPanel>

                    <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                               Orientation="Horizontal"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                               Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />

                    <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                               Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                <Border Name="Border">
                    <ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource FrozenRowScrollViewer}">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

There is a problem however with right aligned columns.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />
</Style>
```

The footer row stays left aligned while normal rows are displayed correctly. Why is that? The footer GridViewRowPresenter.Columns property is bound to the GridView used by other rows so it should align it also.

This also happens without a custom ItemContainerStyle:

```
<GridViewColumn local:SortingProperties.SortField="Hero.Stats.NetWon">
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="X Net won" />
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Hero.Stats.NetWon}" TextAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Still left aligned but it is displayed in bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I drew a border around the right-aligned TextBlock and used snoop to figure out why the width of the column was wrong. Posting a solution if anyone needs it.

By using ListViewItem instead of bare GridViewRowPresenter it got to use proper column sizing:

```
<ListViewItem 
    GridView.ColumnCollection="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
    Content="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource summaryConverter}}"
    Style="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.ItemContainerStyle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridViewColumn local:SortingProperties.SortField="Hero.Stats.NetWon">
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Hero.Stats.NetWon}" TextAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
<GridViewColumnHeader Content="X Net won" />
```

Try it.

Comment: Although this could resolve the problem, you should give a brief explain about why you did this approach, or what he was doing wrong etc. Avoid posting only code please.